# c# Build graphs without a library

Tags: c#, graph

I'm trying to find a way of building graphs (all possible types) without having to use a 3rd party library. Any help or code snippets would be appreciated.

I already tried using ImageSharp, but one of the methods I wanted to use were missing and I'd prefer to not use any libs.

Comment: First of all Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm confused: `I'm trying to find a way of building graphs without having to use a 3rd party` and in the next sentence: `I already tried using ImageSharp`. So what exactly are you looking for? Please amend your question to describe your needs in more detail.

Comment: Oxyplot is open source under MIT. You can get an idea of how charting is done by browsing through their codebase https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot

Comment: _graphs (all possible types)_ A bit too broad for a real task, imo. - I you mean charts use MSChart. If you mean something else you need to be __much__ more focused!

Comment: @PeterCsala I mentioned that I'd rather prefer not to use any libraries, but I attempted to use ImageSharp.